# UIImage view show previous image not updated next one

Tags: iphone, objective-c

UIImage view show previous image not update next one.this is my code

```
[userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Engin shared].imagePath] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dummyImge.png"]];
```

when i come first time on this view where i added this code in my viewdidload function ok first time image update successfully and after that i update a new image on server and get path of that image after uploaded on server and save him a separate class like that

```
[Engin shared].imagePath = [JSON valueForKey:@"image"];
```

and after that i go back to previous view and again come on that view and run this line again

```
[userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Engin shared].imagePath] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dummyImge.png"]];
```

but now this not update the image rather they show the previous image . when i check path of that image they show updated (mean) show new image but when i call function which image path they now previous image

Comment: how i can see it that i am useing ARC or not

Comment: In arc you cannot use release, retain or autorelease check this whether it is allowing in your code or not

Comment: ok then i am useing arc because my code not allow to me releae,retain,autorelease so next

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUrlRequset *request = [NSUrlRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Engin shared].imagePath]];

[userImage setImageWithURLRequest:request 
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dummyImge.png"] 
                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                  //handle success message here
                                  }
                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                  //handle error message here
                                  }];
```

i did not actually run this code , but you can test it your self.

Comment: i am using AFNetwroking and image url updated successfully i have checked url put on web view there showing new image but on UIImageview they show previous image

Comment: have you tried setImageWithURLRequest: with a success block from AFNetwroking ? you can check if that image are right or not.

Comment: so have a try , perhaps you can figure it out in the callback block.